# Nested foreach statements... how to break out of child and continue parent if a match is found

Tags: php

I have an application that is passing a list of system printers to a PHP application. I am trying to set it up to ignore the printers that are basically just "software" printers. As you can see from the code below(which is by no means pretty). That I have an outer(parent) foreach that is looping through the printer list that is provided in a string that is delimited by a "pipe" symbol. Inside of that I have a second(child) foreach, that loops through a list of words that are common in the software printers names (i.e.. Adobe PDF would match the word "PDF")

So my question is this, the parent loop works fine, the printers are inserted in the database from the string, however none of my attempts at filtering out the ones that match the keywords have been excluded. So How would you suggest going about breaking out of the "child" foreach to tell the parent to skip that loop?

```
<?php
// Set all QUEUE Printers to Unavailable, so we can reset as active only those that are present
$SQL = "UPDATE `queues_printers` SET `status`='0' WHERE (`queue_id`='".$_GET['queue']."')";
$result = $mysqli->query($SQL);
// Process Printers
$ignore_names = array("PDF","OneNote","Fax","Microsoft XPS Document Writer","RemotePrinter");
$ignoreit=false;
$today = date("Y-m-d");
// Get list from $_GET[printers]
$printers = explode("|",base64_decode($_GET['printers']));
// Add/Update them
foreach ($printers as $printer){
// Check if this printer is to be ignored(i.e.. pdf printers, fax software, and other software printers are not useful)
foreach ($ignore_names as $ignored) {
    if($ignoreit === false){
    if (strpos($printer,$ignored) === true) {
    $ignoreit = true;
    break;
    }
    }
}
if($ignoreit === true){
$ignoreit = false;
continue;
}
// See if this is an existing printer and update it to available
$SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT id FROM queues_printers WHERE queue_id = '".$_GET['queue']."' AND name = '".$printer."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($SQL);
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
if ($row_cnt > '0'){
    $printer_detail = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $UpdateSQL = "UPDATE `queues_printers` SET `status`='1', `last_seen`='".$today."' WHERE (`id`='".$printer_detail["id"]."')";
    $result2 = $mysqli->query($UpdateSQL);
    $result->close();
}
else{
// Otherwise add it
$InsertSQL = "INSERT INTO `queues_printers` (`queue_id`, `name`, `status`, `last_seen`) VALUES ('".$_GET['queue']."', '".$printer."', '1', '".$today."')";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($InsertSQL);
}
}
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: [break](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) can take a numeric argument indicating the number of levels to break; or put your loops in a function and use `return`

Comment: To the 5 people now that are talking about the indenting, the code is indented by Zend Studio. I have seen thousands of posts on here, that are not indented at all, so can we look beyond the visual aesthetics of a 2 space indent versus 4, Please. Especially when the indenting gets messed up by the way you have to post code on here, by adding 4 spaces to certain areas to get it in the code box.

Comment: @MikeMiller Your *visual aesthetics* caused me to give you several erroneous answers before I probably found the right one, just because I trusted the little indenting you did have, while I shouldn't had trusted them. Indenting is **not** just eye candy. Please take the time to master indenting your code with your IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is really your problem, but this line will never be true:

```
 if (strpos($printer,$ignored) === true)
```

[strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) returns a `false` or an `integer`, but never a `true`.

Furthermore: using `break;` without a parameter is like using `break 1;`, meaning it will only break out of the inner most child loop. This is already what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I switched to a !== false, and it worked like I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `break` statement.

An example

```
 foreach(array(1,1,1,1) as $k) {

      if (!$k) {

            break;
      }
 }
```

It can also have a int value that determines how many nested loops it can break out of,

```
 break 2; // will break out two nested loops
```

To answer your question in more detail wouldn't it be better to just check if they aren't to be ignored and then continue instead of the other way around.

```
foreach($printers as $printer) {

     // Do default stuff to all printers

     if (!strpos($printer,$ignored)) {

          // Do stuff with unignored printers
     }
}
```